# Rails, post-deploy to Heroku: unable to run console, db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems, jwt, environment-variables

Good day,

My team and I are trying to push our Rails app to Heroku - `git push heroku dev:master` is successful, but thereafter `heroku run rails db:migrate`, `heroku run rails console`, etc. all fail with the following error (full trace pasted at bottom of post):

```
   NoMethodError: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/warden-jwt_auth-0.3.6/lib/warden/jwt_auth.rb:89:in `upcase_first_items'
```

I tracked down the failing method `upcase_first_items` in the files of the gem `jwt_auth`, but remain unable to solve this. Searching the error on Google (including iterations of the error) turns up 0 results.

**We successfully pushed this app to Heroku two weeks ago, and have not since changed anything with regards to authentication** (which I've made sure of by reviewing all our commits from the last 2 weeks).

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Michael

Full trace:

```
[cocomio-languages (dev)]$ heroku run rails db:migrate --trace
Running rails db:migrate --trace on ⬢ coco-sprint-3... up, run.2956 (Hobby)
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rails aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/warden-jwt_auth-0.3.6/lib/warden/jwt_auth.rb:89:in `upcase_first_items'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/warden-jwt_auth-0.3.6/lib/warden/jwt_auth.rb:50:in `block in <module:JWTAuth>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/dry-configurable-0.11.1/lib/dry/configurable/setting.rb:119:in `evaluate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/dry-configurable-0.11.1/lib/dry/configurable/setting.rb:70:in `value'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/dry-configurable-0.11.1/lib/dry/configurable/config.rb:111:in `method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/devise-jwt-0.5.9/lib/devise/jwt/railtie.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/dry-configurable-0.11.1/lib/dry/configurable/methods.rb:15:in `configure'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/devise-jwt-0.5.9/lib/devise/jwt/railtie.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `block in execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:75:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:218:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:218:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/app/bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config => environment
```

***Update 1***

I reverted to each commit from the previous two weeks (i.e. between now and the last working deploy), and deployed, but received the same error. I reached commits from even **before** the last deploy (the deploy that was working), and still have the same error, which leads me to believe it has nothing to do with our commits from the last few weeks.

When I went to the Heroku dashboard and reverted the build to the deploy from two weeks ago, the Rails commands (heroku run rails c, heroku run rails db:migrate, etc.) once again work.

Comment: @nuaky after carefully reviewing all commits from the past 2 weeks, I've rolled back our deploy to the one from 2 weeks ago, and tested out the `heroku run rails` commands, and they all work! :( Which means that it must be something from the last 2 weeks. Anything in particular that might have caused a problem to arise? (Other than directly modifying a config file, which nobody did).

Comment: I created a dev copy ("crazyexperiment"), reverted it all the way back to a commit before the previous deploy, pushed to Heroku, but the commands STILL fail, with the same error (...). :( 

The last deploy worked... so something is weird. perhaps something changed on Heroku?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With the version `0.8.0` of [`devise-jwt`](https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt) it's no longer a problem. Please see the breaking change in version `0.7.0`, when upgrading.

---

#### Previous answer

Probably someone or something upgraded the `dry-configurable` gem from version `0.9.0` to `0.11.1`. This gem is a dependency of `warden-jwt_auth` which is a dependency of `devise-jwt` and the new version breaks it.

A few days ago the version [`0.11.0`](https://github.com/dry-rb/dry-configurable/releases/tag/v0.11.0) of `dry-configurable` was released and `warden-jwt_auth` uses it, because it specifies the version of this dependency with `~> 0.6`, which includes the faulty version (everything from `0.6` to `1.0` would be fine). You can see that in the Gemfile.lock or in the dependencies of `warden-jwt_auth`.

If somebody did run `bundle upgrade` it will have pulled the new faulty version.

I recommend you to pin the older version of `dry-configurable` in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'dry-configurable', '0.9.0'
```

Then run `bundle update` and deploy again.

Comment: Awesome, you saved our day(s). `Devise-jwt` is actually specified in our gemfile as `~> 0.5.8`, but we also have `jwt` in there without a version specification. Could it have come from `jwt`? if so, do you recommend that we specify a version for it as well?

Comment: I've updated the question to address your question in the comment above.

Comment: This answer saved my day !

Answer (score 0):

Now my rspec is working with following versions

- rails 6.1.6
- ruby 2.7.5

I needed to install
devise-jwt 0.9.0 from 0.7.0
dry-configurable 0.13.0 from 0.15.0
rspec-rails 5.1.2
. Previously was receiving following gerror

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
ruby-2.7.5/gems/devise-jwt-0.7.0/lib/devise/jwt/mapping_inspector.rb:49:in `formats'
```