# why i have an error when i generate jwt_blacklist model for rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, jwt, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to create an API rails application and adding authentication using DEVISE and JWT

I'm using : 
    Windows 8.1
    ruby 2.6.5p114
    rails 5.2.4 
    devise-jwt (0.5.9)
    devise 4.7.1

When I want to create the model for JWT using this command

```
rails g model Jwt_blacklist jti:string:index exp:datetime
```

I have this error

```
  C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/warden-jwt_auth-0.3.6/lib/warden/jwt_auth.rb:89:in 
  `upcase_first_items': undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

any solutions?

Comment: I'm also getting this error after a bundle update, but I didn't update jwt, warden-jwt_auth, nor devise-jwt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As someone else pointed out in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60318650/7547104) the problem is due to the new `0.11` version of `dry-configurable`, which is a dependency of `devise-jwt`.

The solution is to add `gem 'dry-configurable', '0.9.0'` to your `Gemfile` and run again `bundle update`.