# Adding devise-jwt to a rails api -> How to resolve issue while generating model for JWTBlacklist?

Tags: devise

I'm trying to generate model for JWT blacklist for configuring devise-jwt in a rails api.

I'm facing issue while generating JWT blacklist through terminal. 
I'm trying to pass this command:
    `rails g model jwt_blacklist jti:string:index exp:datetime`

But I'm getting this error:
`` /home/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/warden-jwt_auth-0.3.6/lib/warden/jwt_auth.rb:89:in `upcase_first_items': undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) ``

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Stack-Overflow, please have a look at how to ask a good question, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @SyedSaadAhmed Please let me know if you have any solution for this?

Comment: This is poorly asked, but the answer is in the [git issues](https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt/issues/159).

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to lock the gem as per this [Git issue](https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt/issues/159), so throw this in your Gemfile.

```
gem 'dry-configurable', '0.9.0'
```

This is also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60301010/rails-post-deploy-to-heroku-unable-to-run-console-dbmigrate).